# Defining two dimensional Dynamic Array with different types

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to create two dimension array of different type like I can add to that array two values one of them is controlname and second is boolean value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but won't a Dictionary work for what you trying to do? Are you trying to store Key/Value pairs?

Comment: Using a list with tuples `public static List<Tuple<string, Point>> pixelsArr = new List<Tuple<string, Point>>();`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do that. Instead, you should create a class that contains these two properties, then you can create an array of that type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string ControlName {get;set;}
    public bool MyBooleanValue {get;set;}
}

public MyClass[] myValues=new MyClass[numberOfItems];
```

Or, as Anders says, use a dictionary if one of the properties is meant to be used to perform lookups.

Answer (score 5):

A dictionary will work for what you are trying to do then.

```
Dictionary<string, bool> controllerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
```

To set a value

```
if (controllerDictionary.ContainsKey(controllerName))
    controllerDictionary[controllerName] = newValue;
else
    controllerDictionary.Add(controllerName, newValue);
```

To get a value

```
if (controllerDictionary.ContainsKey(controllerName))
    return controllerDictionary[controllerName];
else
    //return default or throw exception
```

Comment: You can just use `controllerDictionary[controllerName] = newValue;`, the `ContainsKey` and `Add` aren't required

Comment: Ye, that's true, it's only needed for the the get

Answer (score 4):

You can't to that with an array.

Perhaps you should be using a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8bctb9c.aspx)?

A generic dictionary of `Dictionary<string,bool>` appears to be the kind of thing that will work for your description.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to use your array. Do you want to look up the value by a key, or by its index? Konamiman suggested a class. But a class with two types is nothing more than a `Dictionary<type of key, type of value>`.
You can use a dictionary if you want to obtain the value by a key.
Like so:

```
Dictionary<string, int> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
MyDict.Add("Brutus", 16);
MyDict.Add("Angelina", 22);
int AgeOfAngelina = MyDict["Angelina"];
```

Now the disadvantage of a dictionary is that, you can't iterate over it. The order is undetermined. You can not use `MyDict[0].Value` to obtain the age of Brutus (which is 16).

You could use a

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> MyList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```

to iterate through a 2D array of two different types as a `List` supports iteration. But then again, you cannot obtain the age of Angelina by `MyList["Angelina"].Value` but you would have to use `MyList[0].Value`.

But you could use a datatable as well. But it requires somewhat more work to initialize the table with its columns.

Comment: Of course you can extend with LINQ to use queries on your data.

Comment: Since when can't you iterate over a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to lookup/set a boolean by control name, you could use a [`Dictionary<string, bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use Dictionary<string,bool>.
If, for some reason, you really need an array, try object[,] and cast its values to the types you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to create an array of type object, and then add this to an arraylist.
Here is some sample code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Collections
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
                object[] o = new object[3];
                // Add 10 items to arraylist
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    // Create some sample data to add to array of objects of different types.
                    Random r = new Random();
                    o[0] = r.Next(1, 100);
                    o[1] = "a" + r.Next(1,100).ToString();
                    o[2] = r.Next(1,100);
                    ar.Add(o);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"A multi-dimensional array is an array:
all elementsin all dimensions have the same type"

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it with a List. I suggest you take a look at Tuples.

[How to easily initialize a list of Tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002455/how-to-easily-initialize-a-list-of-tuples#answer-43011006)

You can use a list of type object too if you want

Like so :

```
List<List<object>> Dates = new List<List<object>>() { };
Dates.Add(new List<object>() { 0 ,"January 1st" });
```