# How to easily initialize a list of Tuples?

Tags: c#, list, collections, .net-4.0, tuples

I love [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx). They allow you to quickly group relevant information together without having to write a struct or class for it. This is very useful while refactoring very localized code.

Initializing a list of them however seems a bit redundant.

```cs
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create( 1, "cow" ),
    Tuple.Create( 5, "chickens" ),
    Tuple.Create( 1, "airplane" )
};
```

Isn't there a better way? I would love a solution along the lines of the [Dictionary initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx).

```cs
Dictionary<int, string> students = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 111, "bleh" },
    { 112, "bloeh" },
    { 113, "blah" }
};
```

Can't we use a similar syntax?

Comment: In this case why *wouldn't* you use a dictionary instead of a list of Tuples?

Comment: @Ed S.: A `Dictionary` doesn't allow duplicate keys.

Comment: @EdS.: Every time it's not a two-tuple where one item is hashable/orderable and unique.

Answer (score 501, accepted):

c# 7.0 lets you do this:

```
  var tupleList = new List<(int, string)>
  {
      (1, "cow"),
      (5, "chickens"),
      (1, "airplane")
  };
```

If you don't need a `List`, but just an array, you can do:

```
  var tupleList = new(int, string)[]
  {
      (1, "cow"),
      (5, "chickens"),
      (1, "airplane")
  };
```

And if you don't like "Item1" and "Item2", you can do:

```
  var tupleList = new List<(int Index, string Name)>
  {
      (1, "cow"),
      (5, "chickens"),
      (1, "airplane")
  };
```

or for an array:

```
  var tupleList = new (int Index, string Name)[]
  {
      (1, "cow"),
      (5, "chickens"),
      (1, "airplane")
  };
```

which lets you do: `tupleList[0].Index` and `tupleList[0].Name`

**Framework 4.6.2 and below**

You must install [`System.ValueTuple`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) from the Nuget Package Manager.

**Framework 4.7 and above**

It is built into the framework. Do *not* install `System.ValueTuple`. In fact, remove it **and** delete it from the bin directory.

*note: In real life, I wouldn't be able to choose between cow, chickens or airplane. I would be really torn.*

Comment: Can this be used on a .net core 2.0 ?

Comment: @АлексаЈевтић, [`System.ValueTuple`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) supports core 2.0. But, try it without the Nuget first, as unnecessary packages can cause problems. So one way or another, yes. Use c# v7 or greater if possible.

Comment: Here's a relevant [microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) about the collection initializers mentioned in this answer.

Comment: `Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from '(string, string)' to 'System.Tuple<string, string>'  MauiApp1 (net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0) C:\projects\MauiApp1\MainPage.xaml.cs`

Answer (score 240):

Yes! [This is possible](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/list-of-tuples/).

> The *{ }* syntax of the collection initializer works on any *IEnumerable*
>   type which has an *Add* method with the correct amount of arguments.
>   Without bothering how that works under the covers, that means you can
>   simply extend from *List<T>*, add a custom Add method to initialize your
>   *T*, and you are done!

```
public class TupleList<T1, T2> : List<Tuple<T1, T2>>
{
    public void Add( T1 item, T2 item2 )
    {
        Add( new Tuple<T1, T2>( item, item2 ) );
    }
}
```

This allows you to do the following:

```
var groceryList = new TupleList<int, string>
{
    { 1, "kiwi" },
    { 5, "apples" },
    { 3, "potatoes" },
    { 1, "tomato" }
};
```

Comment: A downside is having to write the class. Like you, I love tuples because I don't have to write a class or struct.

Comment: @BillW Not too certain this is the exact post, ... [but I know Jon Skeet has written about it before](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx).

Comment: does this work `groceryList[0] == groceryList[1]` or does a comparison have to be implemented?

Comment: I created a Nuget Package with Add methods on ICollection to save others the time of having to maintain this code. See here for package: https://nuget.org/packages/Naos.Recipes.TupleInitializers See here for code: https://github.com/NaosProject/Naos.Recipes/blob/master/Naos.Recipes.TupleInitializers/.Naos.Recipes/TupleInitializers/Initializers.cs  This will include a cs file in your solution under a ".Naos.Recipes" folder, so you don't have to drag-around an assembly dependency

Comment: ***What's new*** in _each C# version language_: `C# 5, C# 6, C# 7, C# 8, C# 9., C# 10...`

Answer (score 90):

C# 6 adds a new feature just for this: extension Add methods.  This has always been possible for VB.net but is now available in C#.

Now you don't have to add `Add()` methods to your classes directly, you can implement them as extension methods.  When extending any enumerable type with an `Add()` method, you'll be able to use it in collection initializer expressions.  So you don't have to derive from lists explicitly anymore ([as mentioned in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002466)), you can simply extend it.

```
public static class TupleListExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T1, T2>(this IList<Tuple<T1, T2>> list,
            T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        list.Add(Tuple.Create(item1, item2));
    }

    public static void Add<T1, T2, T3>(this IList<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> list,
            T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3)
    {
        list.Add(Tuple.Create(item1, item2, item3));
    }

    // and so on...
}
```

This will allow you to do this on any class that implements `IList<>`:

```
var numbers = new List<Tuple<int, string>>
{
    { 1, "one" },
    { 2, "two" },
    { 3, "three" },
    { 4, "four" },
    { 5, "five" },
};
var points = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<double, double, double>>
{
    { 0, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { -4, -2, 42 },
};
```

Of course you're not restricted to extending collections of tuples, it can be for collections of any specific type you want the special syntax for.

```
public static class BigIntegerListExtensions
{
    public static void Add(this IList<BigInteger> list,
        params byte[] value)
    {
        list.Add(new BigInteger(value));
    }

    public static void Add(this IList<BigInteger> list,
        string value)
    {
        list.Add(BigInteger.Parse(value));
    }
}

var bigNumbers = new List<BigInteger>
{
    new BigInteger(1), // constructor BigInteger(int)
    2222222222L,       // implicit operator BigInteger(long)
    3333333333UL,      // implicit operator BigInteger(ulong)
    { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 },               // extension Add(byte[])
    "55555555555555555555555555555555555555", // extension Add(string)
};
```

---

C# 7 will be adding in support for tuples built into the language, though they will be of a different type (`System.ValueTuple` instead).  So to it would be good to add overloads for value tuples so you have the option to use them as well.  Unfortunately, there are no implicit conversions defined between the two.

```
public static class ValueTupleListExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T1, T2>(this IList<Tuple<T1, T2>> list,
        ValueTuple<T1, T2> item) => list.Add(item.ToTuple());
}
```

This way the list initialization will look even nicer.

```
var points = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>
{
    (0, 0, 0),
    (1, 2, 3),
    (-1, 12, -73),
};
```

But instead of going through all this trouble, it might just be better to switch to using `ValueTuple` exclusively.

```
var points = new List<(int, int, int)>
{
    (0, 0, 0),
    (1, 2, 3),
    (-1, 12, -73),
};
```

Comment: I finally took a decent look at this while updating my library to C# 6.0. Although it looks good at a glance, I prefer my previously posted solution over this because I find `TupleList<int, string>.` to be more readable than `List<Tuple<int, string>>`.

Comment: That's something that a type alias can fix. Granted the alias itself cannot be generic which may be preferable. `using TupleList = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Tuple<int, string>>;`

Comment: I created a Nuget Package with Add methods on ICollection to save others the time of having to maintain this code. See here for package: https://nuget.org/packages/Naos.Recipes.TupleInitializers See here for code: https://github.com/NaosProject/Naos.Recipes/blob/master/Naos.Recipes.TupleInitializers/.Naos.Recipes/TupleInitializers/Initializers.cs This will include a cs file in your solution under a ".Naos.Recipes" folder, so you don't have to drag-around an assembly dependency

Answer (score 47):

You can do this by calling the constructor each time with is slightly better

```
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>
{
    new Tuple<int, string>(1, "cow" ),
    new Tuple<int, string>( 5, "chickens" ),
    new Tuple<int, string>( 1, "airplane" )
};
```

Comment: I couldn't get the original code to work, so I've amended it to what I think it should be... which may reverse your opinion on whether the syntax "is slightly better" after all :)

Comment: at least use `Tuple.Create` instead and you can infer the type arguments

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks @onedaywhen

Answer (score 30):

Old question, but this is what I typically do to make things a bit more readable:

```
Func<int, string, Tuple<int, string>> tc = Tuple.Create;

var tupleList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>
{
    tc( 1, "cow" ),
    tc( 5, "chickens" ),
    tc( 1, "airplane" )
};
```

Comment: Works on old versions of .NET, too!

Answer (score 4):

Super Duper Old I know but I would add my piece on using Linq and continuation lambdas on methods with using C# 7.  I try to use named tuples as replacements for DTOs and anonymous projections when reused in a class.  Yes for mocking and testing you still need classes but doing things inline and passing around in a class is nice to have this newer option IMHO.  You can instantiate them from

> 1. Direct Instantiation

```
var items = new List<(int Id, string Name)> { (1, "Me"), (2, "You")};
```

> 2. Off of an existing collection, and now you can return well typed tuples similar to how anonymous projections used to be done.

```
public class Hold
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//In some method or main console app:
var holds = new List<Hold> { new Hold { Id = 1, Name = "Me" }, new Hold { Id = 2, Name = "You" } };
var anonymousProjections = holds.Select(x => new { SomeNewId = x.Id, SomeNewName = x.Name });
var namedTuples = holds.Select(x => (TupleId: x.Id, TupleName: x.Name));
```

> 3. Reuse the tuples later with grouping methods or use a method to construct them inline in other logic:

```
//Assuming holder class above making 'holds' object
public (int Id, string Name) ReturnNamedTuple(int id, string name) => (id, name);
public static List<(int Id, string Name)> ReturnNamedTuplesFromHolder(List<Hold> holds) => holds.Select(x => (x.Id, x.Name)).ToList();
public static void DoSomethingWithNamedTuplesInput(List<(int id, string name)> inputs) => inputs.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Doing work with {x.id} for {x.name}"));

var namedTuples2 = holds.Select(x => ReturnNamedTuple(x.Id, x.Name));
var namedTuples3 = ReturnNamedTuplesFromHolder(holds);
DoSomethingWithNamedTuplesInput(namedTuples.ToList());
```

Comment: You make me feel old. :) I might be missing something here, but initializing 'holds'  is not concise at all. This was the exact point of the question.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris No, you were right I copied and pasted the wrong bit of code for Point 1.  Need to go a little slower before I hit 'submit'.

Answer (score 1):

One technique I think is a little easier and that hasn't been mentioned before here:

```
var asdf = new [] { 
    (Age: 1, Name: "cow"), 
    (Age: 2, Name: "bird")
}.ToList();
```

I think that's a little cleaner than:

```
var asdf = new List<Tuple<int, string>> { 
    (Age: 1, Name: "cow"), 
    (Age: 2, Name: "bird")
};
```

Comment: That comes more down to taste whether you prefer to mention types explicitly or not, in the same vain as to use `var` or not. I personally prefer explicit typing (when it is not duplicated in e.g. the constructor).

Answer (score -6):

```
    var colors = new[]
    {
        new { value = Color.White, name = "White" },
        new { value = Color.Silver, name = "Silver" },
        new { value = Color.Gray, name = "Gray" },
        new { value = Color.Black, name = "Black" },
        new { value = Color.Red, name = "Red" },
        new { value = Color.Maroon, name = "Maroon" },
        new { value = Color.Yellow, name = "Yellow" },
        new { value = Color.Olive, name = "Olive" },
        new { value = Color.Lime, name = "Lime" },
        new { value = Color.Green, name = "Green" },
        new { value = Color.Aqua, name = "Aqua" },
        new { value = Color.Teal, name = "Teal" },
        new { value = Color.Blue, name = "Blue" },
        new { value = Color.Navy, name = "Navy" },
        new { value = Color.Pink, name = "Pink" },
        new { value = Color.Fuchsia, name = "Fuchsia" },
        new { value = Color.Purple, name = "Purple" }
    };
    foreach (var color in colors)
    {
        stackLayout.Children.Add(
            new Label
            {
                Text = color.name,
                TextColor = color.value,
            });
        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label))
    }

this is a Tuple<Color, string>
```

Comment: How do you get the value/name syntax with a Tuple?

Comment: Compiler tells that anonymous type are not implicitly convertible to Tuple