# Difference Between Collection Initializer Syntaxes

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) states that:

> By using a collection initializer you do not have to specify multiple calls to the Add method of the class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls.

They also give this example, using the newer collection initialization syntax with brackets:

```
var numbers = new Dictionary<int, string> { 
    [7] = "seven", 
    [9] = "nine", 
    [13] = "thirteen" 
};
```

However, when checking the IL code generated, it seems that this code does not at all result in any calls to the `Add` method, but to rather to one `set_item`, like so:

```
IL_0007: ldstr        "seven"
IL_000c: callvirt     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int32, string>::set_Item(!0/*int32*/, !1/*string*/)
```

The "old" syntax with curly brackets in contrast gives the following:

```
// C# code:
var numbers2 = new Dictionary<Int32, String>
{
    {7, "seven"},
    {9, "nine"},
    {13, "thirteen"}
};

// IL code snippet:
// ----------
// IL_0033: ldstr        "seven"
// IL_0038: callvirt     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int32, string>::Add(!0/*int32*/, !1/*string*/)
```

... As you can see, a call to `Add` is the result, as expected. (One can only assume that the text on MSDN mentioned above is yet to be updated.)

I've so far discovered one case where this difference actually matters, and that is with the quirky `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`. This one allows for one key to point to more than one value. Initialization can be done in both ways:

```
const String key = "sameKey";
const String value1 = "value1";
const String value2 = "value2";

var collection1 = new NameValueCollection
{
    {key, value1},
    {key, value2}
};

var collection2 = new NameValueCollection
{
    [key] = value1,
    [key] = value2
};
```

... But because of the differences in how only the former actually calls the `NameValueCollection::Add(string, string)`, the results differ when looking at the contents of each collection;

> collection1[key] = "value1,value2"
>
> collection2[key] = "value2"

I realize that there's a connection between the old syntax and the `IEnumerable` interface, and how the compiler finds the `Add` method by naming convention etcetera. I allso realize the benefits of any indexer type being subject to the new syntax, as discussed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076127/c6s-new-collection-initializer-clarification) before.

Perhaps these are all expected features, from your point of view, but the implications had not occurred to me, and I'm curious to know more.

So, I wonder if there's a source of documentation at MSDN or elsewhere that clarifies this difference in behavior that comes with the choice of syntax. I also wonder if you know of any other examples where this choice may have such an impact as when initializing a `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: The docs you refer to do say this above the 'newer' syntax: *You can specify indexed elements if the collection supports indexing.*. To me, that implies it will use the indexer to do the setting.

Comment: @CharlesMager I was just about to post something similar after seeing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076127/c6s-new-collection-initializer-clarification)

Comment: @CharlesMager It's true what you say, but I'd hardly call that a "clarification", save perhaps to the already enlightened one ;) Also, the question - as far as differences in behavior go - obviously only apply to types that are subject to both "indexing" and "adding", something that is also not discussed on that page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose for the ultimate clarification, you have to go to the specification. The C# 6 spec is not 'officially' released, but there is an [unofficial draft](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/README.md) available.

What's interesting here is that, despite its location in the Programming Guide, the indexer syntax is *not* a collection initializer, it's an object initializer.  From [7.6.11.3 'Collection Initializers'](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/f12213c4ffe77a51dbc5412250bef6af75333f32/expressions.md#collection-initializers):

> A collection initializer consists of a sequence of element initializers, enclosed by { and } tokens and separated by
>   commas. **Each element initializer specifies an element to be added to the collection object being initialized, and
>   consists of a list of expressions enclosed by { and } tokens** and separated by commas. ... The collection object to which a collection initializer is applied must be of a type that implements
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable or a compile-time error occurs. **For each specified element in order, the
>   collection initializer invokes an Add method on the target object** with the expression list of the element initializer as
>   argument list

And from [7.6.11.2 'Object Intializers'](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/f12213c4ffe77a51dbc5412250bef6af75333f32/expressions.md#object-initializers):

> An object initializer consists of a sequence of member initializers, enclosed by { and } tokens and separated by
>   commas. Each member_initializer designates a target for the initialization. An identifier must name an accessible
>   field or property of the object being initialized, whereas **an argument_list enclosed in square brackets must specify
>   arguments for an accessible indexer** on the object being initialized.

Take this as an example:

```
public class ItemWithIndexer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = 
        new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string this[string index]
    {
        get { return _dictionary[index]; }
        set { _dictionary[index] = value; }
    }
}
```

Note that this class *does not* meet the requirements to have a collection initializer applied: it does not implement `IEnumerable` or have an `Add` method, so any attempt to initialize in this way would result in a compile-time error.  This object initializer targeting the indexer will compile and work, however (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ZnvQi)):

```
var item = new ItemWithIndexer
{
    ["1"] = "value"
};
```