# In C#: How to Create a List of Tuples containing a Control and a list of users which are authorized to access this Control?

Tags: c#, list, generics, tuples

I am building a C# application for a law firm. In every `Form` there are some `Control`s which only some of the users can access (for other users - those `Control`s will be disabled).

I have built it like this: There is a class called `AuthorizedForm` that inherits from `Form`. This class has a method called `SetAuthorization`, which enables all the `Control`s the user may access, and disables the rest. Each form in the application inherits from `AuthorizedForm`.

When the user logs in, the `SetAuthorization` method is called and receives as parameters the id of the logged in user, and a list of rules. Every rule consists of a `Control`, and a list of users that can access that `Control`.

The list is actually divided into two lists: user groups (such as lawyers, paralegals etc.) and individual users. So if, for example, I put the id of the group "Administrators" and the id of the group "lawyers" in the first list, and the id of one of the secretaries in the second list - then the `Control` will be defined as `Enabled` for all administrators and lawyers, and also for that secretary, while for the other office employees the `Control` will be defined as `Disabled`.

The list is called `AuthorizationList` and is actually a class that inherits from the `List` class of type `Tuple`, which receives a `Control`, a `GroupList` and a `UserList` (the last two are nothing but a `List` of type `byte`).

**The definition of** `GroupList` **and** `UserList`:

```
public class GroupList : List<byte> { }
public class UserList : List<byte> { }
```

**The code of the** `AuthorizedList` **class** (built with help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002466/1925272) answer)**:**

```
public class AuthorizationList : List<Tuple<Control, GroupList, UserList>>
{
    public void Add(Control control, GroupList groups, UserList users)
    {
        Add(new Tuple<Control, GroupList, UserList>(control, groups, users));
    }
}
```

**The** `AuthorizedForm` **class:**

```
public class AuthorizedForm : Form
{
    public void SetAuthorization(User loggedInUser, AuthorizationList authorizationList)
    {
        foreach (var rule in authorizationList)
        {
            bool isAuthorized = false;

            foreach (byte group in rule.Item2)
            {
                if (group == loggedInUser.Group)
                {
                    isAuthorized = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isAuthorized)
            {
                foreach (byte user in rule.Item3)
                {
                    if (user == loggedInUser.Id)
                    {
                        isAuthorized = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(!isAuthorized)
            {
                rule.Item1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The call for the** `SetAuthorization` **from the login function:**

```
if (user.isLoggedIn)
{
    SetAuthorization(user, new AuthorizationList()
    {
        /*
          CONTROL  |    GROUPS IDS LIST    |     USER IDS LIST
        */        
        { textBox1, new GroupList() { 1, 2, 3 }, new UserList() { 4 } },
        { textBox2, new GroupList() { 1, 2 },    new UserList() { 4 } },
        { button1,  new GroupList() { 1 },       new UserList() { 4, 3 } },
    });
}
```

Now, I want to let `AuthorizationList` be also of type `Tuple` which receives a `Control` and a `GroupList` only, or a `Control` and a `UserList` only, so I can set permissions for user groups only, or for individual users only.

I can not think of a way to do this without significantly changing the code I have written. Is there a way to do this in a relatively easy and elegant way? If not, how would you suggest to do it?

Comment: Can't you pass empty group/user list?

Comment: Well, I could - but It's not very elegant. :(

Comment: I have to agree with @IvanStoev, it should make the most sense to pass an empty list for the group / user. That seems to be the best way given your architecture. Also, suppose you didn't do that and passed in a control and a list. How would you know if you were given a group or a user list?

Comment: What about : List<Tuple<Control, object, object>> ?

Comment: @JohnBustos - the first overload will receive a `GroupList` and the second overload will receive a `UserList`...

Comment: @jdweng - could you elaborate please?

Comment: Actually have two overloads for AuthorizationList.   One exactly like you have and the second List<KeyValuePair<Control, object>>.  Having an object will accept either a GroupList or a UserList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using an object that isn't a Tuple to hold the Authorizations, it's more elegant than Tuple<>:

```
public class GroupList : List<byte> { }
public class UserList  : List<byte> { }

public class Authorization
{
    public Control    Control   { get; set; }
    public GroupList  Groups { get; set; }
    public UserList   Users { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorizationList : List<Authorization>
{
    public void Add(Control control, GroupList groupList, UserList userList)
    {
        Add(new Authorization
        {
            Control = control,
            Groups = groupList,
            Users = userList
        });
    }

    public void Add(Control control, GroupList groupList)
    {
        Add(control, groupList, null);
    }

    public void Add(Control control, UserList userList)
    {
        Add(control, null, userList);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code was more or less good and it answered my question, but it had some problems (missing brackets, unnamed properties and such) so I allowed myself to fix it.

Comment: I incorporated the corrections you've made, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the fact that passing an empty list does not affect your logic.

To make it "more elegant", add two more `Add` overloads to your `AuthorizationList` class:

```
public class AuthorizationList : List<Tuple<Control, GroupList, UserList>>
{
    public void Add(Control control, GroupList groups, UserList users)
    {
        Add(new Tuple<Control, GroupList, UserList>(control, groups, users));
    }
    public void Add(Control control, GroupList groups)
    {
        Add(new Tuple<Control, GroupList, UserList>(control, groups, new UserList()));
    }
    public void Add(Control control, UserList users)
    {
        Add(new Tuple<Control, GroupList, UserList>(control, new GroupList(), users));
    }
}
```

Now you can pass `GroupList`, `UserList` or both:

```
SetAuthorization(user, new AuthorizationList()
{
    { textBox1, new GroupList() { 1, 2, 3 }, new UserList() { 4 } },
    { textBox2, new GroupList() { 1, 2 } },
    { button1,  new UserList() { 4, 3 } },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand your question...
AuthorizationList is a List of Tuples

And you want it to receive only 2 parameters either a a COntrol and  grouplist or a Control and User list

To me it seems like AuthorizationList should be a KeyValuePair>

or something similar. Then check the type to see if the List is a user list or group list

Comment: It's true. the `AuthorizationList` could be a `List` of `Lists`, but could you please elaborate on how to implement it?