# How to create a List of ValueTuple?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, valuetuple

Is it possible to create a list of ValueTuple in C# 7?

like this:

```
List<(int example, string descrpt)> Method()
{
    return Something;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: I'm almost tempted to downvote since this *is* the syntax required to return a list of named tuples. Why the question?

Comment: I suppose the question was about not the return-type of the Method, but rather, about the missing **Something**.

Comment: Related post - [How to easily initialize a list of Tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8002455/465053)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You are looking for a syntax like this:

```
List<(int, string)> list = new List<(int, string)>();
list.Add((3, "first"));
list.Add((6, "second"));
```

You can use like that in your case:

```
List<(int, string)> Method() => 
    new List<(int, string)>
    {
        (3, "first"),
        (6, "second")
    };
```

You can also name the values before returning:

```
List<(int Foo, string Bar)> Method() =>
    ...
```

And you can receive the values while (re)naming them:

```
List<(int MyInteger, string MyString)> result = Method();
var firstTuple = result.First();
int i = firstTuple.MyInteger;
string s = firstTuple.MyString;
```

Comment: It's better to name the fields in the method definition.

Answer (score 13):

Sure, you can do this:

```
List<(int example, string descrpt)> Method() => new List<(int, string)> { (2, "x") };

var data = Method();
Console.WriteLine(data.First().example);
Console.WriteLine(data.First().descrpt);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the existing answers, with regards to projecting `ValueTuples` from existing enumerables and with regards to property naming:

You can still name the tuple properties AND still use `var` type inferencing (i.e. without repeating the property names) by supplying the names for the properties in the tuple creation, i.e.

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(i => (example: i, descrpt: $"{i}"))
    .ToList();

// Access each item.example and item.descrpt
```

Similarly, when returning enumerables of tuples from a method, you can name the properties in the method signature, and then you do NOT need to name them again inside the method:

```
public IList<(int example, string descrpt)> ReturnTuples()
{
   return Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
        .Select(i => (i, $"{i}"))
        .ToList();
}

var list = ReturnTuples();
// Again, access each item.example and item.descrpt
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is best applied to `c# 6` but can be used in `c# 7` as well. Other answers are much more correct because the are tending to use `ValueTuple` instead of `Tuple` used here. You can see the differences [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/#) for `ValueTuple`

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> Method()
{
   return new List<Tuple<int, string>>
   {
       new Tuple<int, string>(2, "abc"),
       new Tuple<int, string>(2, "abce"),
       new Tuple<int, string>(2, "abcd"),
   };
}

List<(int, string)> Method()
{
   return new List<(int, string)>
   {
       (2, "abc"),
       (2, "abce"),
       (2, "abcd"),
   };
}
```

Comment: No need to use "Tuple" at all

Comment: I surely prefer this sintax, is more readable and clear than the others.

Comment: Upvoted. This is the correct syntax for C# 6 and below.

Comment: @Guilherme what? The OP asked specifically about C# 7

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, but this also compiles in C#7, with a older syntax. So, it is one possible answer.

Comment: @Guilherme this completely breaks the naming of "example" and "descrpt" which are the new features of c# 7, so no, it is not an answer

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the answer is correct so I am not sure if he may know or may not know the syntax of creating tuples, that`s why I answered in that way, if you can provide a better answer go ahead and I will vote it up, but voting an answer as wrong just because you can omit a Tuple word does not make sense to me!

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj as I explained above, your version breaks the C# 7 feature of naming the parts of the Tuple. If you don't know C# 7 I'd suggest you not to answer

Comment: Downvoted as this answer is using `Tuple`, not `ValueTuple`.

Comment: There are significant difference between Tuple and ValueTuple in terms of memory usage and performance. When people ask about C# 7 and tuples, they *don't* mean the old Tuples. A Tuple is created on the heap and requires garbage collection. A ValueTuple is created on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for noting that @PanagiotisKanavos, you are right, I had to see the differences about ValueTuple and Tuple, I will add to the answer the difference as well

Comment: The question is about c# 7