# How to find object value in list<object>

Tags: c#

I have a list of area object, how to find object value?

```
List<object> _area = new List<object>();
_area.Add(new { area_pid = _area_pid, info = _area_name });
```

I need to find area_pid in list if it is not found then it adds a new object.

Comment: This is a great use case for not using anonymous objects like this, C# is not JavaScript, if you simply created your self a class to hold this information and not use List<object> you would find your life would be a lost easier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't be bothered creating a full on class for your area (and I don't see why not, it just seems to be a couple of properties, maybe 3 lines of code) you can use a ValueTuple

```
List<(int area_pid, string area_name)> areas = new List<(int, string)>();
areas.Add((3,"New York"));
areas.Add((4,"New Jersey"));
areas.Add((5,"Chicago"));

//find example
var newAreas = areas.Where(a => a.area_name.StartsWith("New"));
```

Personally I'm not a fan over creating a dedicated storage class, but it may be of interest to you. There are a c# 7 / .net 4.7 construct by the way

See for more:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/

[How to create a List of ValueTuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250462/how-to-create-a-list-of-valuetuple)

Comment: I was just about to add ValueTuples +1

Answer (score 4):

**Given**

```
public class Something
{
   public Something(string area, string name)
   {
      Area = area;
      Name = name;
   }

   public string Area { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }      
}
```

**Usage**

Then you could simply use a `Where` statement

```
var somethings = new List<Something>();
somethings.Add(new Something("sad", "bobo"));

var results = somethings.Where(x => x.Area == "asd");
```

Or if you assume there is only one `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault`

```
var result = somethings.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Area == "asd");
```

Comment: This is the route I would go, even though I answered with some intro to the ValueTuple facility

Answer (score 0):

Your can use

```
foreach(Object item in _area) {

  System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = item.GetType().GetProperty("name");
  String yourValue = (String)(pi.GetValue(item, null));
}
```

But, I suggest your to have a model (Class) to store.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use ToList() method for defining _area.

```
var _area = new []{new { area_pid = _area_pid, info = _area_name}}.ToList();
_area.Add(new { area_pid = _area_pid2, info = _area_name2 });
```

Now you could use

```
_area.Where(x=>x.area_pid==1);
```

**Update: Based on comment by Enigmativity,**

```
var _area = new []{new { area_pid = default(int), info = default(string)}}.Take(0).ToList();
_area.Add(new { area_pid = _area_pid2, info = _area_name2 });
```

Comment: If you had a `.Take(0)` before the `.ToList()` then this would be a great answer.