# C# How to create and initialize a static array of ValueTuples?

Tags: c#, arrays, tuples, static-initialization

I want to initialize a static readonly array of ValueTuples, I'd like to use the approach from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002455/how-to-easily-initialize-a-list-of-tuples):

```
var tupleList = new (int Index, string Name)[]
  {
      (1, "cow"),
      (5, "chickens"),
      (1, "airplane")
  };
```

But it doesn't work for a static member, I have to declare the type of tupleList.  I can do it as a Tuple like this, but I don't know how to do it as a ValueTuple:

```
static readonly Tuple<uint, string>[] tupleList= new Tuple<uint, string>[]
{
    new Tuple<uint, string>(0x1, "string1"),
    ...
};
```

But I'd prefer to use the cleaner format if I can figure out the right type, so far I've tried a variety of types with no luck.

Comment: I am having no issue with the following: `static readonly (int id, string name)[] Tuples = new [] { (1, "hello"), (2, "world") };`. What code have you tried that is causing the issue, and what is the error the compiler gives you?

Comment: This is not unique to tuples, you can't use `var` to declare class members, which means you can't use anonymous types either.

Comment: Personal preference, but _every_ time I think of using a Tuple, I tell myself there'd be more clarity with a class, and I opt for creating a class. Even if it's just a POCO. What's the benefit of a tuple, in your scenario?

Comment: Note that that's not a different syntax for the same code.  The first snippet is using `ValueTuple` instead of `Tuple`, which impacts the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I actually did try the correct approach so now I'm thinking that perhaps this tool does not support this feature properly.  The benefit of a tuple is to keep the code shorter.  It's only being used in this one module so a class is not particularly useful.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is marked as a duplicate, the question is not why a class field can't be marked as var, please read the question carefully!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the "cleaner" `var` (implicit, but still strongly typed) type but you can initialize a tuple as the commenters have suggested. The "cleanest" you can get away with is this, which uses type inference on the array:

```
(int Index, string Name)[] tupleList = {
    (1, "cow"),
    (5, "chickens"),
    (1, "airplane")
};
```

That, at least, allows you to avoid specifying the type twice, which is one reason people use `var`.

The language does not support the use of `var` when declaring member variables. This is true of both static and instance fields.

There's a [historic reason](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/) for this. That's not to say it couldn't change if you propose a change and it's vetted by the community.

Comment: Does this tuple spec only work with var then?

Comment: @AlanMoore only [*local* variables can be implicitly typed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables). Class members must be explicitly typed.

Comment: @AlanMoore It has nothing to do with tuples.

Comment: Although the answer is correct, the `You can't` part is wrong because the question was not whether or not it's possible to use `var`. @AlanMoore All you need to do is replace `var` with `(int id, string name)[]` in your first code block and you're good to go. Check [Jonathon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5402620/jonathon-chase) above.

Comment: I'll make that more clear.

Comment: Thanks @AhmedAbdelhameed!  That is correct, it appears that many have misread my question.