# Sorting an arraylist in c# regarding to its sub-elements

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` which its elements are an `Array`. What I want to do is to sort this `ArrayList` using elements of `Array`. To clarify, let's suppose we have the following arraylist:

```
arraylist{[10,2], [6,3], [12,2]}
```

Then I want to sort it in descending order using dividing each elements of arrays to each other(array `a_i = [a_i,b_i] ==> sort using max(a_i/b_i)`), i.e., in the following form:

```
arraylist{[12,2],[10,2],[6,3]}
```

I tried using `Sort()`, but it is for a list not for an `ArrayList` as I know. Would anyone please let me know how I could sort it in an efficient way to avoid a high complexity?

Thanks!

Comment: ArrayList is basically depracted and should be replaced by List<T>

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including sample inputs (in code) **and expected results for those inputs**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` is deprecated and you really should not use it anymore..:

> [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8): We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List class.

Let's assume you have created a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` maybe like this:

```
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    new Tuple<int, int>(10,2 ),
    new Tuple<int, int>(6,3),
    new Tuple<int, int>(12,2)
};
```

Then the result can be created with Linq, maybe like this:

```
var sorted = tupleList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item1 / x.Item2);
```

This omits any checks for div by zero..

To make the initialization a bit shorter you can use a function..

```
Func<int, int, Tuple<int, int>> tc = Tuple.Create;
```

..taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002455/how-to-easily-initialize-a-list-of-tuples) and write:

```
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    tc(10,2 ),
    tc(6,3 ),
    tc(12,2 )
};
```

Comment: In the same vein I would prefer ValueTuple over Tuple because you don’t need the class semantics of a Tuple and a ValueTuple has a much smaller footprint and more succinct syntax, i.e. `var tupleList = new List<(int dividend, int divisor)> { (10, 2), (6, 3), (12, 2) };` which also saves you defining a somewhat awkward Tuple.Create surrogate function.

Comment: While true it takes an even newer .Net version.

Answer (score 3):

Like someone said in the comments, you're better off using `List<T>`.  But here's how to do it using Sort() with an IComparer()

```
class DivisionComparer : IComparer<int[]>, IComparer
{

    public int Compare(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        double xval = (double) x[0] / x[1];
        double yval = (double) y[0] / y[1];
        return yval.CompareTo(xval);
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return Compare((int[]) x, (int[]) y);
    }
}


class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var x = new ArrayList()
        {
            new [] {6,3},                
            new [] {12,2},
            new [] {10,2},

        };
        x.Sort(new DivisionComparer());
        foreach (var el in x)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(",", (int[]) el));
        }
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
12,2
10,2
6,3
```