# C# Linq _ Create new tuple collection of products according to conditions

Tags: c#, linq

let's say I have a class:

```
class Product
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Category { get; set; }

  public double Price { get; set; }

  public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

and list of class objects:

```
List<Product> productList = new()
{
  new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Pasta", Category = "Beverages", Price = 18.0, Number = 39 },
  new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Anchius", Category = "Beverages", Price = 19.0, Number = 0 },
  new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Syrup", Category = "Condiments", Price = 10.0, Number = 13 },
  new Product { Id = 4, Name = "Seasoning", Category = "Condiments", Price = 22.0, Number = 53 },
  new Product { Id = 5, Name = "Gumbo", Category = "Condiments", Price = 21.35, Number = 41 },
  new Product { Id = 6, Name = "Spread", Category = "Condiments", Price = 25.0, Number = 120 },
  new Product { Id = 7, Name = "Dried", Category = "Confections", Price = 30.0, Number = 0 },
  new Product { Id = 8, Name = "Bread", Category = "Confections", Price = 16.0, Number = 14 },
  new Product { Id = 9, Name = "Sauce", Category = "Condiments", Price = 40.0, Number = 20 },
  new Product { Id = 10, Name = "Niku", Category = "Meat", Price = 97.0, Number = 29 },
  new Product { Id = 11, Name = "Niku", Category = "Meat", Price = 34.0, Number = 61 },
  new Product { Id = 12, Name = "Ragoo", Category = "Seafood", Price = 31.0, Number = 31 }
};
```

TODO 1: create new tuple collection if 'Number' property equals 0. The first element of tuple should be "Category" and second - array of Products.
return type:

```
IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> products)> result1
```

result should be:

```
("Beverages",
    new Product[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Pasta", Category = "Beverages", Price = 18.0, Number = 39 },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Anchius", Category = "Beverages", Price = 19.0, Number = 0 },
    }
),
("Confections",
    new Product[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 7, Name = "Dried", Category = "Confections", Price = 30.0, Number = 0 },
        new Product { Id = 8, Name = "Bread", Category = "Confections", Price = 16.0, Number = 14 },
    }
)
```

TODO 2: create new tuple collection if 'Number' property doesn't equals 0. The first element of tuple should be "Category" and second - array of Products.
return type:

```
IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> products)> result2
```

result should be:

```
("Condiments",
    new Product[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Syrup", Category = "Condiments", Price = 10.0, Number = 13 },
        new Product { Id = 4, Name = "Seasoning", Category = "Condiments", Price = 22.0, Number = 53 },
        new Product { Id = 5, Name = "Gumbo", Category = "Condiments", Price = 21.35, Number = 41 },
        new Product { Id = 6, Name = "Spread", Category = "Condiments", Price = 25.0, Number = 120 },
    }
),
("Meat",
    new Product[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 10, Name = "Niku", Category = "Meat", Price = 97.0, Number = 29 },
        new Product { Id = 11, Name = "Niku", Category = "Meat", Price = 34.0, Number = 61 },
    }
),
("Seafood",
    new Product[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 12, Name = "Ragoo", Category = "Seafood", Price = 31.0, Number = 31 },
    }
)
```

Please help.
Please give both Query syntax and Method syntax solutions.

Comment: @Jamiec can you please answer this question?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use this linq:

```
var result1 = productList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category, (category, products) => new List<(string Category, IEnumerable<Product> Products)>
        { (category, products) }

    ).Where(x => x[0].Products.Any(s => s.Number == 0)).Select(x => x[0]);

var result2 = productList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category, (category, products) => new List<(string Category, IEnumerable<Product> Products)>
        { (category, products) }

    ).Where(x => x[0].Products.All(s => s.Number != 0)).Select(x => x[0]);
```

The T-Sql query is a little tricky and remember you must turn t-sql result to your tuple model, this is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE #product(Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(50), Category NVARCHAR(50),Price DECIMAL(10,1), Number INT)

INSERT INTO #product
(
    Id,
    Name,
    Category,
    Price,
    Number
)
VALUES
(   1,N'Pasta',N'Beverages',18.0,39),
(   2,N'Anchius',N'Beverages',19.0,0),
(   3,N'Syrup',N'Condiments',10,13),
(   4,N'Seasoning',N'Condiments',22,53),
(   5,N'Gumbo',N'Condiments',18.0,41),
(   6,N'Spread',N'Condiments',18.0,120),
(   7,N'Dried',N'Confections',18.0,0),
(   8,N'Bread',N'Confections',18.0,14),
(   9,N'Sauce',N'Condiments',18.0,20),
(   10,N'Niku',N'Meat',18.0,29),
(   11,N'Niku',N'Meat',18.0,61),
(   12,N'Ragoo',N'Seafood',18.0,31)

--get product with 0 nubmers
SELECT * FROM #product WHERE Category IN (
SELECT x.Category FROM (
SELECT *,CASE Number WHEN
0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NewNumber FROM #product) x
GROUP BY x.Category
HAVING SUM(x.NewNumber)>0
)

 --get product without 0 nubmers
SELECT * FROM #product WHERE Category IN (
SELECT x.Category FROM (
SELECT *,CASE Number WHEN
0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END NewNumber FROM #product) x
GROUP BY x.Category
HAVING SUM(x.NewNumber)=0
)
```

Comment: Thanks but It's not a type of "IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> products)>" and you did not gave Query sintax solution

Comment: @DeveloperMister  you mean t-sql query?

Comment: Yes, and return type should be "IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> products)>"
@Saeed Esmaeelinejad

Comment: can you please convert your results to "IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> products)>" ? @Saeed Esmaeelinejad

Comment: @DeveloperMister Now that's what you want.

Comment: You gave a type of "new { string category, IEnumerable<Product> products }" but I need:
("Meat",
    new Product[]
    {
        new Product { ... },
        new Product { ... },
    }
),
("Seafood",
    new Product[]
    {
        new Product { ... },
        new Product { ... },
    }
)
@Saeed Esmaeelinejad

Comment: tank you for sql solution but query syntax is this: https://static.javatpoint.com/tutorial/linq/images/linq-syntax3.png @Saeed Esmaeelinejad

Comment: I gave the idea to get what you need and the SO is place to get idea not exact code, the tuple has some limitation maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002455/how-to-easily-initialize-a-list-of-tuples and also you said T-Sql not linq query!

Comment: Anyway thank you very much. your last update solved my problem. Tanks! @Saeed Esmaeelinejad

Answer (score 0):

(Method syntax only)

This is perhaps a somewhat overkill solution, but it lets you traverse `productList` only once by creating a dictionary where the keys are `true` (for `result1`) and `false` (for `result2`). Since first posting this answer, I have supplemented it with a second implementation version.

---

The first version groups products by category **according to each `Product`'s `Number` value** (`Number == 0` and `Number != 0`); adhering to your written requirements:

> TODO 1: create new tuple collection if 'Number' property equals 0
> TODO 2: create new tuple collection if 'Number' property doesn't equals 0

```csharp
IDictionary<bool, IEnumerable<( string category, IEnumerable<Product> products)>> results = productList
    .GroupBy(
        product => product.Number == 0,
        ( isZero, products ) => ( 
            NumberIsZero: isZero, 
            ProductsByCategory: products.GroupBy(
                product => product.Category,
                ( category, products ) => ( category, products ))))
    .ToDictionary(item => item.NumberIsZero, item => item.ProductsByCategory);

var result1 = results[true];
var result2 = results[false];
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/719srI).

---

The second version groups products by category **based on whether each category contains any `Product` with `Number == 0`, or not**; adhering to your requested example outputs:

```
IDictionary<bool, IEnumerable<( string Category, IEnumerable<Product> Products )>> results = productList
    .GroupBy(product => product.Category,
        ( category, products ) => ( Category: category, Products: products ))
    .GroupBy(productsByCategory => productsByCategory.Products.Any(p => p.Number == 0),
        ( containsZero, productsByCategory ) => ( ContainsZero: containsZero, ProductsByCategory: productsByCategory ))
    .ToDictionary(
        gr => gr.ContainsZero,
        gr => gr.ProductsByCategory);

var result1 = results[true];
var result2 = results[false];
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UyMUiD).

Comment: @ Astrid E. No, it's not working at all. please read carefully question and result pease of code

Comment: @DeveloperMister I find that your example results don't fit your written requirements. I tried to match your written requirements, filtering on the `Number` value for each `Product`.

Comment: Tuple value names are now added.

Comment: Everything is ok with my question. 'Saeed Esmaeelinejad' has almost answered my question but can't convert to "IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> products)> type

Comment: Then we simply disagree on that. For what it's worth, I have added an implementation that adheres to your example outputs. Method syntax only, though.