# How do I create arrays with different types

Tags: c#, arrays

I need my array to store a bool and string pair.

```
MyType[,] array1 = { {true, "apple"}, {false, "orange"} };

// Later in my code.
for (i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    if(array1[i, 0] == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array1[i, 1]);
    }
}
```

How do I get the above in `C#` without using collection? 
If not possible, which collection should I use?

Comment: You cannot have 2 different types in normal arrays

Comment: You will have to create a class/struct to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining two dimensional Dynamic Array with different types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939443/defining-two-dimensional-dynamic-array-with-different-types)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays can't have different datatypes. It is the design principle of Arrays. Instead, create a class/struct and then create array/list of that class. Something as following,

```
class MyClass
{
bool flag;
string myStr;
}

List<MyCLass> myList=new List<MyClass>();
ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList(); //or use this option
```

You should be able to access list using `foreach` in c#.

Comment: yeah i thought of using list but i need to stop looping at the last value of the array or list, as I need to do some string manipulation to the last item.
Edit: Reason for using array is it loops faster than list or collection.

Comment: You can get the size of list, by using `myList.Count` and then add if clause for the last element while running `foreach`. If you are worried about performance then use ArrayList. Edited answer accordingly :)

Comment: `ArrayList`?  Really?  I haven't run any benchmarks, but I can almost guarantee that performance with an `ArrayList` will be worse, because of the boxing/unboxing required.  Better to use either a `List<T>` or a regular array of the class objects.

Comment: @Tim oops.. You are right, `ArrayList` will have performance issues of boxing/unboxing :|. Now, I guess OP has to go with `List<T>`.