# Do multidimensional arrays have to be of the same type?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am re-learning how to code, but with a new-ish language; please forgive if this or any questions I ask seem a little off the wall.

As the title says.   I don't have any code as of yet, but I find that I want to create an array that keeps track of an item name and the weight of said item on the same index.  So what I want to do is create something like

array[string[] ItemName, int ItemWt[]];

Looking at this maybe I need a struct, but I haven't figured those out in C# with forms development, yet.

I am using Microsoft's Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Take a look on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939443/defining-two-dimensional-dynamic-array-with-different-types

Comment: All elements of an array, multidimensional or not, must have the same unified static type. (The same also holds for other collection types like Lists.. use aggregate objects as relevant.)

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking for arrays and didn't see anything for lists.  But that helps.  Thanks again.

Comment: You need a collection of classes, not of structs.

Comment: Create a class (`public class Item { public string Name {get; set;}; public int Weight {get; set;}}`). Create instances of your items and add them to a collection (you'll be happier with a `List<Item>` than an array of Items)